# Best way to change the configuration in a containerised .NET Framework web apps?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker

What's the best way to change the configuration in a containerised .NET Framework web apps?

It's all based around web.config so passing environment variables isn't possible, like you'd expect using .net core.

I'm thinking about pulling out config sections in to seperate files:

```xml
<appSettings configSource="config\appSettings.config"/>
```

And then maybe mounting the config directory to the host when running the container.

Is this the best approach? - I can't seem to find anything with google... hence the question.

Comment: What mean _change_ ? Change a node(s) on XML config, change the file entirely ? Why not ENV variable ? You can write a small Powershell /bash script to replace the ENV value to xml.

Comment: We've got different configuration setup in each environment (dev, test, prod) trying to get an idea which is the best approach to take to change these configuration values while using 1 container image. I'd normally use env vars in new .net core, however, that would mean code changes for the current code which could become complex.

Comment: Like Max said, you don't need code changes. You can set environment variables, have an app update the config file based on the environment variables prior to launching your app.